# How to detect within an Android worker that within a sequence of Workers a previous worker has failed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Im investigating Android Workers.

```
api "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0-alpha01"
```

Im creating unique work that entails multiple workers running in sequence

```
Worker_A -> Worker_B -> Worker_C
```

In the event either `Worker_A` or `Worker_B` returns `Result.failure()` is there any approach I can take to detect this within `Worker_C`

Comment: `Worker_C` won't run at all if `Worker_A` or `Worker_B` failed - a failure stops the chain entirely. What use case are you trying to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in WorkManager's [Chaining Work documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work):

> Chains of `OneTimeWorkRequest` execute sequentially as long as their work completes successfully (that is, they return a `Result.success()`). **Work requests may fail or be cancelled while running, which has downstream effects on dependent work requests**.

To answer your question:

> In the event either `Worker_A` or `Worker_B` returns `Result.failure()` is there any approach I can take to detect this within `Worker_C`?

No, `Worker_C` cannot detect a failure of `Worker_A` or `Worker_B` because it is not going to be run at all.

[Chaining and Worker statuses](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work#work-statuses) covers this in detail.